# Use if statement with variables that are dynamic variables with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, validation, if-statement

Basically I'm trying to create a validator for birthdays using the last information (mm/dd) but it is not returning the value as expected

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
today = mm + '/' + dd;
var newday = today.toString();


var birthday = "1992/09/21";
var monthday = birthday.substr(birthday.length - 5);


function validator(newday, birthday) {
    if (monthday === newday) {
        console.log('True');
        return true;
    }
    else {
        console.log('False');
        return false
    }
}
validator();
console.log(newday, monthday)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
today = mm + '/' + dd;
var newday = today.toString();
console.log('New Date is', newday)


var birthday = "1992/09/21";
var monthday = birthday.substr(birthday.length - 5);
console.log('Month day', monthday)


function validator(newday, birthday) {
    if (newday === birthday) {
        console.log('True');
        return true;
    }
    else {
        console.log('False');
        return false
    }
}
validator(newday, monthday);
//console.log(newday, monthday)
```

Answer (score 0):

> `momentjs` is a light weight javascript library, used for
>   **validating**, manipulating and formatting date.

It provide wrappers to get month, year and date.

```js
var date = new Date();
//Get todays Day and month in "DD/MM" format
var newday = moment(date, 'YYYY/DD/MM').format('DD/MM');
console.log("newDay: " + newday);


//Get birthdate Day and month in "DD/MM" format
var birthday = moment("1992/09/21", 'YYYY/MM/DD').format('DD/MM');
console.log("birthday: " + birthday);

function validator(newday, birthday) {
    if (newday === birthday) {
        console.log('True');
        return true;
    }
    else {
        console.log('False');
        return false
    }
}
validator(newday, birthday);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

For more details you can visit [moment.js page](https://momentjs.com/docs/)